# How can I change this regex in order to validate phone number without internation prefix?

Tags: regex

I am not so into REGEX and I am finsing some problem to adapt this regex that verify a phone number to my use case.

I have this REGEX validating phone number with international prefix: https://www.regextester.com/97440

```
(([+][(]?[0-9]{1,3}[)]?)|([(]?[0-9]{4}[)]?))\s*[)]?[-\s\.]?[(]?[0-9]{1,3}[)]?([-\s\.]?[0-9]{3})([-\s\.]?[0-9]{3,4})
```

It correctly validates string as: **+39 3298494333** but it doesn't validate string representing a number without the international prefix, for example this string doesn't match my regex **3298494333**

How can be changed in order to accept also phone number that doesn't have the prefix?

Comment: That is because if there is no `+` the minimum length is 11 characters

Comment: @Thefourthbird mmm and can it be changed in order to accept also this type of string?

Comment: You could change `[0-9]{4}` to `[0-9]{3}` but I am not sure if that will make it a good pattern. There are a lot of optional things, and it could possibly also match `+1)1)111 1111` Perhaps this page can be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123559/how-to-validate-phone-numbers-using-regex

Answer (score 0):

Use this fix:

```php
(?:(?:\+\(?[0-9]{1,3}|\(?\b[0-9]{4})\)?)?\s*\)?[-\s.]?\(?[0-9]{1,3}\)?[-\s.]?[0-9]{3}[-\s.]?[0-9]{3,4}
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/Juo8eS/1).

**Explanation**

```php
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture (optional
                           (matching the most amount possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?:                      group, but do not capture:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      \+                       '+'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      \(?                      '(' (optional (matching the most
                               amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      [0-9]{1,3}               any character of: '0' to '9' (between
                               1 and 3 times (matching the most
                               amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      \(?                      '(' (optional (matching the most
                               amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      \b                       the boundary between a word char (\w)
                               and something that is not a word char
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      [0-9]{4}                 any character of: '0' to '9' (4 times)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    )                        end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \)?                      ')' (optional (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )?                       end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s*                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \)?                      ')' (optional (matching the most amount
                           possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [-\s.]?                  any character of: '-', whitespace (\n, \r,
                           \t, \f, and " "), '.' (optional (matching
                           the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \(?                      '(' (optional (matching the most amount
                           possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [0-9]{1,3}               any character of: '0' to '9' (between 1
                           and 3 times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \)?                      ')' (optional (matching the most amount
                           possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [-\s.]?                  any character of: '-', whitespace (\n, \r,
                           \t, \f, and " "), '.' (optional (matching
                           the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [0-9]{3}                 any character of: '0' to '9' (3 times)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [-\s.]?                  any character of: '-', whitespace (\n, \r,
                           \t, \f, and " "), '.' (optional (matching
                           the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [0-9]{3,4}               any character of: '0' to '9' (between 3
                           and 4 times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
```